# Why doesn't the error message work when incorrect login used?

Tags: php, html, mysql, login-script

I just started learning php this week. I've been working on what I thought would be a simple php login form. Whenever I run the index.html code and enter the login details, the submit button takes me to front.html regarless of whether or not the details are correct. In my understanding this means that the connection didnt happen. I've looked all over and the other stuff online has bugs and wont work either. Please help me to understand why this code doesnt work and how to fix it please.
The index.html code is below.

```
 <?php 
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="main">
         <h1>Sign in</h1> 
         <div id="login"> 
         <fieldset>
            <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
               <ul> 

                  <li><label>Username</label> <input type="text" size="30" name="username" required></li>
                  <li><label>Password</label> <input type="password" size="30"     name="password" required></li>
                  <li><input type="submit" value="Sign in"></li>              
               </ul>
            </form>
         </fieldset>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And this is the login.php code

```
 <?php
// establish MySQLi connection

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proj4");
if (!$con)
{
die("Connection was not established: ". mysqli_connect_errno());
}
// checking the user
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
$get_user = "SELECT * FROM user where username ='$user' AND password='$password'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);
$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
if($check_user>0){
$_SESSION['username']=$user;
echo "<script>window.open('front.html','_self')</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script>alert('username or password is not correct')</script>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems here, one of which is that your form's password element `name="password"` doesn't match the value in your query, being `$_POST['pass']`

Change it to `$_POST['password']`

The other being the following conditional statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
```

You have no element named "login", which I think you want to use this with your submit button.

- Nothing inside that conditional statement will execute.

Therefore, you will need to change your submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="login">
```

You're also using sessions. You're missing `session_start();` in your login.php file. It's required to be inside all pages when using sessions.

Another thing, is that I am pretty sure you are trying to run `.html` files as PHP. Unless you specifically instructed Apache to treat .html files as PHP, you will need to rename all those to `.php`. Your `index.html` file contains PHP code. Rename it to `index.php`.

If `front.html` contains PHP code, then you will also need to rename it to `front.php`.

If you're trying to run your code from your own computer and haven't installed a webserver, that includes PHP/MySQL/Apache, then that is another issue. You will need to run this from a hosted service, or install a webserver on your computer.

- PHP files are not parsed like `.html` files are by a web browser.

**Nota:** I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors, which would have signaled it.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thanks it still didnt work, I know about the hash function, I just wanted to get this part working first, which it still hasnt

Comment: @user3555512 I made a few edits since you last saw my answer. Reload it, I found something else. The one about the submit button and conditional statement.

Comment: @user3555512 Btw, is your entire code inside "one" page; HTML form and SQL? Or, are they two seperate files? I'm doubting it's one file, but I had to ask. Far as I can tell, my answer should work. Make sure everything's correct in your table, columns, types, lengths, existing data etc.

Comment: Those are valuable suggestions. It still doesn't work. In torch it shows the login code after I press submit. The login and index are different files. I'm jus thinking there should be an error of some sort. It doesnt even do that

Comment: @user3555512 What do you mean it shows the login code?

Comment: @user3555512 Ok, I see now. Your `index.html` file, it contains PHP. You need to rename it to `index.php`. You can't run PHP from an `.html` file, unless you specifically instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. If you're running all this from your own computer; is PHP/SQL/Apache installed? Or, are you running this from a hosted service?

Comment: after I fill out the form, it displays a page with the raw php code. If I use firefox it goes to the front.html i specified but the form doesnt show errors for wrong input

Comment: @user3555512 If `front.html` contains any PHP code, again... the same as I said above. `.html` files don't run like PHP unless you specifically instructed Apache to treat .html files as PHP which I doubt you're doing since you say everything comes out as code.

Comment: I'm using my own computer. I'm running xamp with apache on. When i change it to php it jus shows code in the browser

Comment: @user3555512 Then your server/system isn't properly configured. You will need to consult the documentation. I can't help you with that. I run Wamp, I know nothing about Xamp. If you made any changes to PHP/Apache etc. you will need to restart all services and possibly your PC, maybe even a fresh install.

Comment: How are you accessing those files btw? Are you using `file://` or `http://localhost/www/`? @user3555512 there is a big difference between those two.

Comment: file://. Whats the difference and how do I use the alternative?

Comment: @user3555512 You **must** use `http://localhost/path/to/your/file.php` in order for the files to be parsed. You can use `file://` for `.html` files, but not when it comes to `.php` files and in your PC. Xamp must have assigned a default folder for you. Please consult the documentation.

Comment: @Fred-ii- more often than not, in xampp, the docroot is `c:/xampp/htdocs/(folder project name or whatever)`, then just straight up `http://localhost/test/index.php`, thats the default, unless the OP setup some things on virtual hosts, of course it'll probably change. this should cover all bases code wise. confusion must be on the env setup

Comment: @Ghost Thanks Ghost. Well, the OP's going to have to go through the documentation. I'm not entirely sure about what the OP's experience is. I've installed a webserver and was up and running 5 minutes after the install. Xamp, that I've never installed it before, but I imagine it resembles Wamp. If it contains PHP/MySQL/Apache, then they're basically the same.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, there are difference in terms of their folder structure but its just basically put those php files on the docroot and should be the same approach. based on this answer, this should work just fine now. but actually the problem has now digressed, its unrelated to what has been posted lol :D.

Comment: well mission accomplished then!